# PHP Round With Decimal & Comma $1,000

Tags: php, rounding, number-formatting

```
<?= round(number_format($vehicle->prices['total_rental'], 2, '.', ',') * 0.50,2) ?>
```

I would like the output to round up to the next 2 decimal places (for money / dollars & cents).

This works great when `$vehicle->prices` is `below $1,000`.  When `$vehicle->prices` is `above $1,000`, it just outputs `.50`.  What is the correct way to round to next `hundredth (i.e $1,452.62)` ?

I have been trying round and `number_format`.  I cannot seem to get either one to produce the correct output when a comma becomes involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do an equation, than round and as the last one thing use `number_format`.

```
echo number_format(round($vehicle->prices['total_rental'] * .5, 2), 2, '.', ',');
```